# Why is the header not fixed while scrolling?

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I have tried css properties for `position:fixed`. I also tried `position:sticky, top:0`, but the header is not fixed.

Here is my code, as you can see, I am using react and antd as component library.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Row, Col } from "antd";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
   return (
     <div>
       <Row className="header">
         <Col
           span={24}
           style={{
             background: "#0392FD",
             position: "sticky",
             top: 0
           }}
         >
          <div>
            <Row>
              <Col>Col1</Col>
              <Col>Col1</Col>
              <Col>Col1</Col>
            </Row>
          </div>
        </Col>
       </Row>
       <Row className="content">
         <Col span={24} style={{ height: "120vh" }}>
           Content
         </Col>
       </Row>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

I know there are many solutions and I tried a lot of them.

Comment: Add a [mcve] **in the question itself** and not only a link to an external resource (which may be offline, blocked or not reachable for some other reason...)

Comment: Try with position: fixed !important

Comment: ```position: fixed; top: 0; width: 100%```
should be working.

Comment: Your style is applied to column inside header, not to header div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead

```
<Row className="header">
<Col
  span={24}
  style={{
    background: "#0392FD",
    position: "sticky",
    top: 0
  }}
>
```

You should write it this way

```
<Row
    className="header"
    style={{
        background: "#0392FD",
        position: "sticky",
        top: 0
      }}
>
<Col span={24}>
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/7lyym9y7j)

Why? `Col`'s parent is `Row`. Both are the same height. `Col` will stick only if its parent is higher and during scrolling `Col` will disappear. It will never happen because as I said they're both the same height. If you set `position: sticky` on `Row` which parent is containing whole page (parent is higher than web browser window) `position: sticky` will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has to be on the header, Not on the div inside your header

Just add this to your style.css file

```
.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}
```

It works fine.